# Copy and paste cells if Duplicate columns , Excel Macro

Tags: excel

I am not very techi-but I have been recording and editing basic Excel Macros for a little while. I have found a few results which almost match my issue, however I am struggling to adapt it so I am hoping someone might be kind enough to help me?!

my issue:

**Sheet 1**

a/b/c/d

name/black/blue/green

Sam/1//1

Jill//1/

Jill/1//

Sam//1//

Sam/1/1/1

I have a name data base with duplicates in it. I need to de-dupe these, copy just one name (column a) onto a new page, and in the process I don't want to lose some of the data (column b-d) which might be in a duplicate name but not in the one going to be copied over.

Outcome I am hoping for:

**Sheet 2**

a/b/c/d

name/black/blue/green

Sam/1/1/1

Jill/1/1/

I have quite a few columns to search for data my example is b-d however it is actually AP-EC so it would be helpful if it is obvious which figures I might need to change...?

Thanks in advance.

Kez

Comment: Yes it is always 1 (Binary data) However I have had this issue before and one which includes words too would be even better? :)

Comment: Hi This looks great, thanks I shall give it a go. Thanks for the speedy reply :)

Comment: What error? Can you post your edited version of strSQL?

Comment: Do I need to change the strSQL, what does it refer to?

strSQL = "SELECT a.[Name], " _

Comment: It refers to the column headings, in your example you have name/black/blue/green, which I used in setting up the code. If you have a sheet, or can create a sheet identical to the example you posted and test the code against that, it would be useful.

Comment: Hi I have done this however it is still showing an error at the srtSQL. 'No value given for one or more required perameters, then points to 'rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3'. Would I need to add "" around ["Name"]? Thanks

Comment: This is code I tested, so I am a little confused. Which sheet? Did you use Sheet3 or change the sql to reference the right sheet? Yes, add braces, it may help and it won't hurt, but I do not think it is causing this problem.

Comment: You could also try a very simple line of sql, for example:

SELECT * FROM [Sheet3$]

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with SQL at all....it has now got problems with: 'cn.Open strCon'. Sorry to be bugging you but my knowledge is pretty limited in this area. Do I need to point it to the name of the document I am working on? Thanks

Comment: I will add some comments to the sample code.

Comment: Hi it has worked! Thanks, I think it is because there was no sheet 5...durr! Thank you so much you have saved many hours. My friend was right to reccomend your site! Kez

Comment: Just a quick one. There are about 100 columns I want to check against...instead of adding in the headings into the code is there a way of changing it to AB:DE or something similar?

Thanks

Comment: I have noticed there is also a limit on the amount of '& "(SELECT Max([W]) FROM [Sheet1$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As W, " _' that I can add on....?

Answer (score 1):

You could try ADO, for example:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strWhere As String
Dim i As Integer

''http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246335

''This saves the name of the active workbook, as this is an example, it is best 
''to save before running the code.
strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

''This is a standard connection string for Excel and ADO, it depends on strFile
''being the name of the current workbook, it should be, because that is 
''what the first line does
''Note also HDR=Yes, this means that the code expects the first row to be headers,
''in this case, Name, Black, Blue, Green
''You can get more on connection strings from: http://www.connectionstrings.com/
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"


''This creates the objects needed in the code
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

''This opens the connection 
cn.Open strCon

''This is fairly ordinary SQL, if you are having problems, try a simpler statement
''such as 
''SELECT * FROM [Sheet3$]
''It is important that you choose a sheet that exists in the activeworkbook
''and that the sheet has data.
strSQL = "SELECT a.[Name], " _
       & "(SELECT Max([Black]) FROM [Sheet3$] b WHERE b.[Name]=a.Name ) As Black, " _
       & "(SELECT Max([Blue]) FROM [Sheet3$] b WHERE b.[Name]=a.Name ) As Blue, " _
       & "(SELECT Max([Green]) FROM [Sheet3$] b WHERE b.[Name]=a.Name ) As Green " _
       & "FROM [Sheet3$] a " _
       & "GROUP BY a.[Name]"


''This uses the connection (cn) to open a recordset with the SQL (strSQL) 
''3, 3 refers to the cursor and lock type.
''More here: http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/met_rs_open.asp
rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

''All this does is put headers in sheet of your choice, I chose sheet5.
For i = 0 To rs.fields.Count - 1
    Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.fields(i).Name
Next

''This copies the recordset into the sheet of your choice, 
''Sheet5 again, in this case
Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```